# CM4 - no touchscreen

Tags: usb, touchscreen

I had a Raspberry Pi 4 with a generic 7” touchscreen and it worked fine but it broke so I copied the system (LineageOS) to CM4 module, enabled USB and it works. Beside the touch function for the screen.

I then flashed it with Raspberry Pi OS and the touchscreen doesn’t work either.

I have 2 different I/O boards and two of those displays. On none of these I can get it to work.

What am I missing?

PS: Display is HDMI and touch goes over USB

**EDIT**: some more info:

lsusb:

```
:/ # lsusb                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0201
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 062a:5918
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:0221
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:1006
```

I have currently also a USB hub, keyboard and mouse connected.

dmesg

```
[  704.922603] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  705.924628] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  705.967627] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  706.016489] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  706.104153] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  707.143912] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  707.193120] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  707.242098] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  707.329459] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  708.345556] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  708.394265] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  708.444622] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  708.540045] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  709.524755] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  709.566443] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  709.609145] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  709.696579] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  710.680801] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  710.729394] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  710.783098] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  710.861646] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  711.804294] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  711.853575] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  711.909957] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  711.999223] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  712.945432] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  712.995501] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  713.065730] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  713.150054] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
[  714.154473] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.rpi4.usb.rc:63)
[  714.200263] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:20)
[  714.250467] init: Command 'symlink /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/ffs.adb /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/f1' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:22) took 0ms and failed: symlink() failed: File exists
[  714.354631] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (/system/etc/init/hw/init.usb.configfs.rc:23) took 0ms and failed: property 'sys.usb.controller' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.usb.controller}'
```

:/ # ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.3 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.3.2 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.3.2:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3.2/1-1.1.3.2:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.3.2:1.1 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3.2/1-1.1.3.2:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.3:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.5 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.5:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.5/1-1.1.5:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1.5:1.1 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.5/1-1.1.5:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1.1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2021-11-16 12:31 usb1 -> ../../../devices/platform/soc/fe980000.usb/usb1
```

Comment: can you see the touch device when you `lsusb`?

Comment: Hey @Bravo thanks for your comment. I added it to my original question

Comment: *I added it to my original question* - removing all the useful information ... personally, I'm not going to lookup USB VID/PID to find out what devices your system has to see which one may be the touch screen

Comment: I haven’t removed any information. Why would I?  This is how the output looks on android. I am a bit confused by that too

Comment: *on android* ... I thought you were showing the output on your CM4 module running Pi OS - not sure what "android" has to do with raspberry pi CM4

Comment: There is LineageOS (android) for Raspberry Pi

Comment: As far I can say the touchscreen isn't listed there

Comment: And it doesn't appear in Raspberry Pi OS either? Must have broken when the Pi 4 broke

Comment: Unlikely. As I wrote I have two of those displays and two of those CM4 modules.

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around.

Since the usb ports are powered off by default, the screen doesn't get recognized at boot because the usb device isn't powered. My current work around is to power the touchscreen from an outside power source then plug the usb touchscreen to the CM4 once the system has booted.